# Plugin [id: 'com.gradle.enterprise', version: '3.2'] was not found in any of the following sources

Tags: java, spring, gradle

gradle version: 6.7.1
springframework version : 5.0.x

In the process of building spring source code,The error message is as follows：
Plugin [id: 'com.gradle.enterprise', version: '3.2'] was not found in any of the following sources

how can solve it~